# How to change the size of react-select and size of react-select dropdown icon

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I want to change the size of react-select icon and tried to make a bigger input field. I tried this code but it didn't change the size of react-select icon. How can I make the input field bigger and size of the icon smaller?

```
const customStyles = {
control: base => ({
   ...base,
      height: 22,
      minHeight: 20,
      width: 57,
      
      
}),
indicatorSeparator: base => ({
  ...base,
  minHeight: '1px',
  height: '2px',
}),
 
indicatorsContainer: base => ({
     ...base,
     height: 20,
     minHeight: 10,
     width:24,
     
     
 }),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use container for container styling and menu for menu styling

```
styles={{
  container: () => ({
    width: 150,
    paddingRight: 2,
  }),
  menu: (provided, state) => ({
    ...provided,
    width: 150,
  }),
}}
```